# How do I isolate my computer from other computers on the network?

Tags: security, webserver, vlan

I have a home web server that only a few people can access. I forward ports on the router so that they can access it.

The web server is hidden behind an openVPN server that I configured on the same network.

I want to know how to isolate a computer with openVPN so that it cannot communicate with other computers (except for the web server) on this network, for security reasons.

I wanted to configure a VLAN on the router, but it seems that my technicolor tc7200 router does not support this feature.  Are there any other options on how to isolate the server from other devices?
A firewall is not enough for protection, if a hacker breaks into the server, he can change the settings and I don't want him to be able to communicate with other devices on this network.

Comment: if you don't trust the host, there really isn't anything else you can do on the LAN except via switch protocols like VLANs. Other than adding an extra layer of network, so you could force the server through a firewall to reach your other hosts, there isn't a system external to the server in question that could control the communication. Often corperate networks will put servers in a DMZ area inside the gateway firewall, but outside the network core firewall. this lets clients reach out to the servers to admin them, but prevents the servers from connecting to clients unsolicited.

Comment: @FrankThomas, Thanks. I am using vbox for servers. I have configured a NAT network. Is it possible to configure the firewall on the main host so that it cannot communicate with other computers? If a hacker breaks into the server, he will also have to break into the virtual machine, - it’s not that easy ..)

Comment: Or, i can use PfSense...